# Push Notifications in Android for particular user

Tags: android, parsing, push-notification

I am having an app developed and in that its for the restaurant manager so i want to add the push notification to the manager on receiving the order. so how is it possible.? i want to notify that particular manager only who has received an order on the web. I want to develop that as soon as the website receives an order for particular restaurant the notifications should be sent to the restaurant manager about that order. how is it possible?

Comment: Di you check Google Cloud Messaging?? http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 1):

For implementing you need Server +GCM+ web services

First user will be logged in the app through Facebook, Gmail or custom authentication.

Parameter(email or password also device id of android Phone) will go to the server through web services(by rest soap etc) and saved on database.

The logic of the code will be

If any user select food sent a request to server and server will sent it to the restaurant manager's device

for more information 
please refer http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html & http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/